# How to select weekends with an interval between them?

Tags: c#

How can I select all weekends until the end of the year, with some criteria to be followed?

User input desired Weekend day:

```
18/12/2021
```

Software must out:

```
25/12/2022 (must be ignored)
01/01/2022
08/01/2022 (must be ignored)
15/01/2022
22/01/2022 (must be ignored)
29/01/2022 and so on...
```

What i have now:

```
public void GetWeekends() {
   var lastWorkedWeekend = dateTimePicker1.Value;
   var workedInSunday = checkBox1.Checked;
   var list = new List < DateTime > ();

   var weekends = GetDaysBetween(lastWorkedWeekend, DateTime.Today.AddDays(365)).Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
   var selected = true;
   for (int i = 0; i < weekends.Count(); i++) {

     if (selected == false) {
       list.Add(weekends.ElementAt(i));
       selected = true;
     } else {
       selected = false;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How to code this will depend on the criteria to be followed.  Without a specification, there is no right answer to your question.  Please be more specific.

Comment: @adv12 i added some code there

Comment: Your 2021 abruptly jumps to 2022 in your output. Why?

Comment: 1. What does "must be ignored" mean? 2. Is the criteria every other Saturday, starting with the second Saturday after the entered Saturday? I don't see any weekends anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd just scroll the input day forward until it was saturday (or calculate it, but i find the loop more self documenting than casting DayOfWeek to an int and factoring for sunday being 0) then add 14 days repeatedly. This skips over the 25th, etc..

```
var d = new DateTime(2021, 12, 18);

while(d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
  d += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

while(d.Year == 2021){  //was your 2022 a typo? or maybe make this <= 2022.. I'm not sure what you want there..
  d += TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
  Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

You might prefer `DateTime.AddDays()`..

Comment: Probably the `while()` condition would be `iterator.Year == input.Year`, variable references mutatis mutandi (it's wrong to name a calculated variable `input`).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a method that creates an enumerable of dates. Once that's done you can use LINQ queries. If creating that enumerable is expensive you could just create one large range encompassing years and re-use it.

Or you might find better performance by just creating the range you need for each query.

```cs
public static class DateRanges
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateOnly> GetRange(DateOnly start, DateOnly end)
    {
        for (var date = start; date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            yield return date;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear from your code what the criteria is, but this does what you described - all weekends from now to the end of the year.

```cs
var today = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Today);
var lastDayOfYear = DateOnly.FromDateTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 12, 31));
var dates = DateRanges.GetRange(today, lastDayOfYear);
var weekendsOnly = dates.Where(date =>
    date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
```

Or if you prefer to create one date range and query it repeatedly:

```cs
// Big range of dates, 10 years into past and future.
// Create this once and re-use it
var dates = DateRanges.GetRange(
    DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-10)),
    DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(10)));

var today = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Today);
var lastDayOfYear = DateOnly.FromDateTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 12, 31));

var weekendsOnly = dates.Where(date =>
    date >= today
    && date <= lastDayOfYear
    && date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
```

In either case if you want every other Saturday you can add

```cs
.Where((date, i) => i % 2 == 0);
```

Or to maintain that readability you could put that in another extension like

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> EveryOther<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.Where((date, i) => i % 2 == 0);
}
```

so your query looks like

```cs
var everyOtherWeekend = dates
    .Where(date =>
        date >= today
        && date <= lastDayOfYear
        && date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    .EveryOther();
```

I wouldn't position this as a better answer than those that iterate over a series of dates. The difference is that instead of having to write a method for any query you can start with a range of dates and then use LINQ to filter it. That makes it a little easier to read and  to compose different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you want to get the date of every second weekend from an initial date until the end of the year. In your example, you kinda bleed over to the next year.

```
public static void Main()
{   
    var dates = GetDateTimeRange(new DateTime(2021, 12, 18), new DateTime(2023, 1, 1), TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
    
    foreach (var dateTime in dates.Skip(1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateTimeRange(DateTime startingDate, DateTime endDate, TimeSpan interval)
{   
    var lastDate = startingDate;
    while (lastDate < endDate)
    {
        yield return lastDate;
        lastDate = lastDate.Add(interval);
    }
}
```

This returns

```
01/01/2022 00:00:00
01/15/2022 00:00:00
01/29/2022 00:00:00
02/12/2022 00:00:00
02/26/2022 00:00:00
03/12/2022 00:00:00
03/26/2022 00:00:00
04/09/2022 00:00:00
04/23/2022 00:00:00
05/07/2022 00:00:00
05/21/2022 00:00:00
06/04/2022 00:00:00
06/18/2022 00:00:00
07/02/2022 00:00:00
07/16/2022 00:00:00
07/30/2022 00:00:00
08/13/2022 00:00:00
08/27/2022 00:00:00
09/10/2022 00:00:00
09/24/2022 00:00:00
10/08/2022 00:00:00
10/22/2022 00:00:00
11/05/2022 00:00:00
11/19/2022 00:00:00
12/03/2022 00:00:00
12/17/2022 00:00:00
12/31/2022 00:00:00
```